# How can I get the value of a EditTextCell in GWT when the user finish editting it

Tags: gwt

I am new at GWT, and I have been trying to get the value of a EditTextCell which is inside a cellTable, So I was wondering what is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to sent the changed details to server for any processing? or need to handle the changes in client side itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you've got an EditTextCell in a CellTable, I assume you mean that you have an entire column like that:

```
Column<RowObject, String> editTextCellColumn = new Column<RowObject, String>( new EditTextCell() ){

  @Override
  public String getValue(RowObject object) {

    // return the value that is supposed to be displayed in the EditTextCell

  }
};
```

If that is the case, you can simply add a fieldupdater to the column. The FieldUpdater is triggered every time the user successfully edits the text cell.

```
editTextCellColumn.setFieldUpdater( new FieldUpdater<RowObject, String>(){

  public void update(int index, final RowObject object, final String value) {

      // 'value' is the new value the user entered in the EditTextCell.
      // 'object' is the object that contains the old row information.
      // 'index' is the current row index of 'object'
      // Code for performing whatever you want to do with the new value goes here. 

  }
};
```